# Can't install Web Standards Update in Visual studio.net 2010

Tags: windows-7-x64, visual-studio-2010

I have Vs.net 2010 Sp1 on my system and want to install "Web Standards Update" for add HTML5 & CSS3 support to it. But when run "Web Standards Update" setup file show alert about download Visual Studio.Net 2010 SP1 but I have already installed it.
What is problem?

Comment: You should provide more information to get an answer. Something like the error code would probably help, though you could probably Google that faster than we could help you.

Comment: I tried all possibles in Google but unfortunately couldn't find any solution. But about more information please say what you want to know?

Comment: You could try the installation logs to see what went wrong, though my recommendation is to simply simply uninstalling the whole of VS2010. Make sure you also uninstall the updates and (if needed) create backups of certain plugins/tokens/settings you wish to keep. Then start over with a clean installation.